# Uploading filedata from API Call to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file, mongoose, gridfs

Im receiving filedata from an API call from an external service.

I want to save this filedata to my MongoDB. I was met with the error that the files are too large.

I went to research GridFS as an extra collection in my MongoDB.

I really cant find anything that solves my issuse. Ive tried to use multer to upload the data like this:

```
  async function addFileDataToDB(fileData) {
    const storage = new GridFsStorage({
      url: mongoose.connection,
      file: (req, file) => {
        console.log(file.mimetype)
        if (file.mimetype === 'application/pdf') {
          return {
            bucketName: 'fileBucket'
          };
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
    });
    const upload = multer({ storage });
    upload(fileData)
    console.log('YAY! : - )')
  }
```

Doesnt seem like something i can use. If i understand it correctly i cant use multer to transfer the data received by the endpoint to MongoDB. Multer seems more like something you would use to upload files from a form etc.

Im looking for any kind of help to point me in the right dirrection to upload this file data from the endpoint to a collection in mongoDB.

To clearify the file data is in the format of a buffer containing bytes, and im trying to do this in nodejs/express

Im new to GridFS, keep that in mind.

Comment: You can have a look at blob storage. https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/storing-large-objects-and-files/

Comment: are you using express and/or bodyParser? and are you sure that the file too large error is thrown at saving in MongoDB, it can be at the receive request level,